# Very slow performance on fitting Keras model in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, keras, kaggle

I have installed Anaconda and Python 3.5 on Windows 10. 
When I try a sample model, it took a long time for the first epoch so I never get into the second epoch!

Here is my model:

```
def larger_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(30, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(15, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Also I got this message when I' executing the python code:

```
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
```

I tried to fit the model on Kaggle and each epoch lasts less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have not g++ installed on your system. If you are on Windows, you need to install two things:

1) **TDM-GCC** : This can be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/). You need to add the path of this to your environmental variables as well.

2) **OpenBLAS** : This can be downloaded from [here](http://www.openblas.net/). Add the path to this to your theano flags in .theano file.

Comment: Just installed TDM-GCC and noticed no difference in the training speed. An online course instructor was using an i7 cpu, as am I, and his training time was 180s compared to my 12600s (both using i7 cpus and identical code). There has to be something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

On windows10 64bit hyperV machine, I train keras model

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      GaussianNoise(0.1),
      Conv2D(filters=Conv2DSize, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", 
        activation="relu"),
      MaxPool2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      Conv2D(filters=Conv2DSize*2, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", 
        activation="relu"),
      MaxPool2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      Conv2D(filters=Conv2DSize*4, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", 
        activation="relu"),
      MaxPool2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      Dropout(0.2),
      Flatten(),
      Dense(units),
      Dense(exam.output_size)]
    )
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

1st epoch took 168s (600ms/step)  (CPU usage about 70%)

2nd epoch took 592s (2s/step)    (CPU usage about 15%)

3rd epoch took 818s (3s/step)       (CPU usage about 15%)

4th epoch took 1055s (4s/step)       (CPU usage about 13%)

Time for each epoch is increased

I use Python 3.8.8, tensorflow 2.3.0, tensorflow-mkl 2.3.0
But when I run the same code on another Win7 64bit Vmware machine, time for each epoch is about 244s and do not increase.